# Pie Chart is not getting rendered while I use it in Angular with dc.js

Tags: angular, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I am able to console.log everything. And everything looks good. The Chart alone isn't rendering. Is there something wrong with the way I defined the dc.js functions? Should it not be done inside the subscribe? Do you guys have any solution?

```
ngAfterViewInit() {

  this.sessionService.getList(this.page).pipe(
    map(({
      sessions
    }) => sessions)
  ).subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);

    const chart = dc.pieChart(`#pieChart`, `interactive-sessions-report`);
    const ndx = crossfilter(res);
    // const all = ndx.groupAll();

    const yearDim = ndx.dimension((d) => {
      console.log(d.openDate);
      return new Date(d.openDate).getFullYear();
    });

    const sessionsPerYear = yearDim.group();
    console.log(sessionsPerYear);
    chart
      .height(10)
      .dimension(yearDim)
      .group(sessionsPerYear)
      .radius(100)
      .height(100)
      .width(100);
    console.log(chart);
    console.log(chart.render());

    chart.render();
  });
}
```

Comment: Please check if the `#pieChart` div exists in the page.

Comment: https://dev.to/jwp/angular-why-doesn-t-my-data-show-up-4efm. Try this